# AWS credentials not being picked up by AWX template

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I've got a new Ansible AWX server running and one of the things I'd like to do with it is to create an AMI of AWS instances before then installing regular updates to the instances.

I've got the playbooks working well with regards to installing updates, but I cannot get the AWX UI to correctly pass AWS credentials via a template.

I'm running a test template which only does the AMI creation and i consistently fails with a message about not finding the credentials.

AWX has a credentials section. I've added the access key and secret key of an IAM user that has the right permissions to do this. Despite adding that credentials to the job template, this is the output I am getting:

```
{
    "_ansible_parsed": true,
    "exception": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_fj8G6M/ansible_module_ec2_ami.py\", line 433, in create_image\n    image_id = connection.create_image(**params).get('ImageId')\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", line 320, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", line 610, in _make_api_call\n    operation_model, request_dict)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py\", line 102, in make_request\n    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py\", line 132, in _send_request\n    request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py\", line 116, in create_request\n    operation_name=operation_model.name)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py\", line 356, in emit\n    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py\", line 228, in emit\n    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py\", line 211, in _emit\n    response = handler(**kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/signers.py\", line 90, in handler\n    return self.sign(operation_name, request)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/signers.py\", line 157, in sign\n    auth.add_auth(request)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/auth.py\", line 356, in add_auth\n    raise NoCredentialsError\nNoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials\n",
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "botocore_version": "1.12.16",
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "enhanced_networking": null,
            "purge_tags": false,
            "launch_permissions": null,
            "ramdisk_id": null,
            "no_reboot": false,
            "ec2_url": null,
            "aws_secret_key": null,
            "billing_products": null,
            "state": "present",
            "virtualization_type": "hvm",
            "sriov_net_support": null,
            "architecture": "x86_64",
            "profile": null,
            "image_location": null,
            "description": "",
            "tags": {
                "Name": "i-sdfsdf987987"
            },
            "kernel_id": null,
            "image_id": null,
            "wait_timeout": 900,
            "wait": false,
            "aws_access_key": null,
            "name": "i-sdfsdf987987",
            "security_token": null,
            "delete_snapshot": false,
            "region": "eu-west-2",
            "instance_id": "i-sdfsdf987987",
            "root_device_name": null,
            "validate_certs": true,
            "device_mapping": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "Error registering image: Unable to locate credentials",
    "boto3_version": "1.9.16"
```

And this is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: "{{ remote_user }}"
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: create an ami
      ec2_ami:
        instance_id: "{{ instance_id }}"
        name: "{{ instance_id }}"
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        tags:
          Name: "{{ instance_id }}"
```

If I add the credentials manually as a variable on the host in the AWX UI, then add the lines:

```
aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
```

then all is well. But that would seem to ignore the obvious advantages of using the credential storage support of AWX.

Environment details:

- ansible 2.6.4
- awx version 1.0.7.2
- ubuntu 18.04.1

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so in the end I have instead configured AWS credentials on each machine and done it this way. It seems like it should be possible to do it the way I was originally trying, but I need this working.

On the target machine, make sure that `awscli tools` are installed, then run `aws configure` to add credentials, a default region, and if you like a default output option.

You'll also need to make sure `pip`, `boto` and `botocore` are installed.

I then updated by playbook like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: "{{ remote_user }}"
  tasks:
    - name: create an ami
      ec2_ami:
        instance_id: "{{ instance_id }}"
        name: "{{ instance_id }}-{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601_basic }}"
        tags:
          Name: "{{ instance_id }}-{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601_basic }}"
```

As you can see, I removed `region` as this is specified on each machine, and tweaked how I name the AMIs. I also removed `become` because the AWS configuration is not done under the root user so having this also causes a failure.